# How to cut small portion of a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to remove a small portion (around 10 seconds) of a long video (2 hours). How can I do it using FFMPEG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:30:00 -t 10 -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

- `-ss 01:30:00` offset time. In this example it is 1 hour 30 seconds. Could also be declared in seconds, `-ss 5400`.
- `-t 10` duration.
- `-c copy` (optional). If you add this as an output option (between `input.mp4` and `output.mp4`) it will use [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. Like a copy and paste, so re-encoding is avoided. However, `ffmpeg` can only cut on key frames, so the offset may not be accurate.

See [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for more info on `-ss` and `-t`.